# Can Mocking/Stubbing happen without the actual class file?

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit, stubbing

I was wondering if Mocking/Stubbing can be done without the original class file that has to be mocked/stubbed?

Comment: Then what are you mocking / stubbing?

Comment: But all the examples I have seen requires the main class file to be included that has to be mocked. 

Can u show me a mocking/stubbing example where the original class file to be mocked is NOT included and will have the following:


Class Name: FriendFinder...

Has Method: Find...

Returns: array with firstname, lastname and email address...




Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

With PHPUnit Mocks (you must set the methods when creating the mock):

```
$sut = $this->getMock('DummyClass', array('dummyMethod'));
$sut->expects($this->once())
    ->method('dummyMethod');
$sut->dummyMethod();
```

With Mockery:

```
$sut2 = \Mockery::mock('DummyClass2');
$sut2->shouldReceive('dummyMethod')
    ->once();
$sut2->dummyMethod();
```

Comment: okay, and these DummyClass and DummyClass2 does NOT need to exists, correct?

Comment: Yep, those are classes that don't exist. You can try the code as is.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Works like a charm. I also wanna simulate that this Class "DummyClass" also has another public method that returns 'true' and I wish to call both them....  is there anyway to do this? I was tring this....but not sure how to make each method return a specific value .. kindly check this code  and assist me http://paste.ofcode.org/rfcHxiXzHcBXcqp6NjxMWy

Comment: Add another expects sentence dont mix them